# C++ Help - I can't seem to figure out the last part of this code

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the program to display the current height of the child and the estimated height of the child.

I have it displaying the before and after for the first child but can't get it to display the estimated height for the rest of the children.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me figure this out. Thanks!

Here is the code that I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double height [10];
    double chgHeight [10];

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        height[x] = 0.0;
        chgHeight[x] = 0.0;
    }

    cout << "You will be asked to enter the heights of ten children."<< endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {   
        cout << "Enter height of child " << endl;
        cin >> height[x];
    }

    chgHeight[0] = height[0] * .05 + height[0];

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {   
        cout << "Child " << x+1 << ": Current " << height[x] << " Expected "<< chgHeight[x] << endl;
    }

    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (If it is, that's ok - it should just be tagged as such - people here will help, they're just not going to do it for you.)

Comment: Brian, this was home work yesterday but I have a final exam coming up in two weeks and I'm still trying to understand this one. I turned it in yesterday, but the last part of this one was as I showed in the code. Thanks!

Comment: I added onto my answer, see if that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

```
chgHeight[0] = height[0] * .05 + height[0];
```

You're only ever setting the first child's `chgHeight`.

**Edit:**

For your output, you're going through the array or heights, which is indexed by the child number (`x`):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
{   
    cout << "Child " << x+1 << ": Current " << height[x] 
         << " Expected "<< chgHeight[x] << endl;
}
```

Your estimated height is calculated from the child's current height, which you have in this loop ( `height[x]` ).  So, you have everything you need right there to output the estimated height.

If you have no need to save the calculation for later, there's really no need to create a second `chgHeight[]` array in your code; just calculate and output the estimated height in that loop for each child.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the estimated height for the rest of the children, only the first:

```
chgHeight[0] = height[0] * .05 + height[0];
```

Put that in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
chgHeight[0] = height[0] * .05 + height[0];
```

This line only calculates the estimated height of the first child. You'll need to put this in a loop as well (changing the indices to your loop variable) to calculate all 10.

Comment: I tried putting it in a loop but I must still be doing something wrong.